# retrieve the database name in an extension

Tags: ee2, add-on-development, database

I'm building a small plugin for EE and I need to retrieve the name of the database. ( specified in config > database.php )

But I can't seem to find any docs that point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say that [Database Class is initialized automatically](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html).

A var_dump(ee()->db) show us that the name of database can be retrieved by, on EECMS 2.6+:

```
ee()->db->database
```

And on EECMS 2.5.5-:

```
$this->EE->db->database
```

Comment: seems reasonable :)  where did you find this ?

Comment: I improved my answer, @janvl. Please, forgive me.

Comment: ah, no problem Robson, I was just wondering where you found it, so I don't have to trouble you guys with silly questions like these in the future.